# Search box cannot display result and always display no result even though keyword is match to the database in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a search box, and the result will display on the same form.

The problem is I don't know why the result is always "no result", even though the keyword should match some of the records in my database, and the name of the table and column are correct. This is my code:

```
<html>
<Title>search </title>
<Body>
<form action = " " method = "POST" method = "GET">
<font  size  = 7 face = "arial rounded MT bold">
WELCOME to VPMG Tradings
</font>

<p align = left>
Enter product name or bar code : <input type = "text" name = "search" > <input type ="submit" name = "searched" value = "Search">
</align>
<br>

<table border = 5 align = center >
<tr><th>Barcode  </th><th>Item name </th><th>Description</th><th>Amount</th><th>Stock</th><th>Location</th>
</tr>
<?php
mysql_connect( "localhost" , "admin" , "123") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("minimart_database") or die(mysql_error());
$output = "";
if (isset ($_POST ["search"] )) {
        $searchq = $_POST ["search"];
        $searchq = preg_match("/[A-Z  | a-z]+/","", $searchq);
        $result ="SELECT * FROM stock WHERE ( barcode  = '%". $searchq ."') OR (itemname =  '% ".$searchq ."')";
        $query = mysql_query ($result) or die (mysql_error ());
        $count = mysql_num_rows ($query);
        if ($count ==0){
        $output = 'no results';
        }
        else{
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query)){
        $barcode = $row['barcode'];
        $itemname = $row['itemname'];   
        $description = $row['description'];
        $amount = $row['amount'];
        $stock = $row['stocks'];
        $location = $row['location'];

        $output = '<div> '.$barcode.' '.$itemname.' '.$description.' '.$amount.' '.$stock.' '.$location.' </div> ';
}
}
}

?>
<?php print ("$output"); ?>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is full of SQL injections that could allow an attacker to steal data from your database, or damage it - please consider switching to parameterised queries. The old `mysql_` functions are soon to be deprecated. Additionally, your HTML should not have spaces around each `=`, the standard notation is `attribute="value"`.

Comment: Sorry because i am just new in using php so i can't understand some of your terminologies . please help me because this is my school project and i need to find out my mistake

Comment: Best thing to do is look up the MySQLi class in the PHP documentation and go from there. When used correctly they protect you from attacks such as SQL injection. You really shouldn't ever be using any of the `mysql_` functions.

Comment: i did what you said. but it is still not working and this is the result Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\xampp\htdocs\home.php on line 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$searchq = preg_match("/[A-Z  | a-z]+/","", $searchq);
```

makes a string to zero.
Use `mysql_real_escape_string($searchq);`

and also in query where clause use like instead of =

**Sugesstion: Use mysqli/PDO since mysql is deprecated**

Comment: i did what you said but it is not working. result is this Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in D:\xampp\htdocs\home.php on line 30. please help me to figure out what is wrong. because this is my school project. please.

Comment: mysqli_select_db($connection,'database')

Answer (score 0):

the code sometimes need to be hard coded to make it work.  i used this code to make my search box work and it is working :

```
<?php
mysql_connect( "localhost" , "admin" , "123") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("minimart_database") or die(mysql_error());
?>

<form id="home_id" method ="POST"  enctype ="multipart/form-data">
<script>
function submitForm(action)
{
document.getElementById('home_id').action=action;
document.getElementById('home_id').submit();
}
</script>
<p align=left><input type="text" name="search" placeholder="enter barcode or item name"><input type="submit" name="searched" onclick="submitForm('finalhome.php')">
<?php
$output="";
if (isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq=$_POST['search'];
$searchq=mysql_real_escape_string($searchq);
$order="SELECT * FROM stock WHERE barcode LIKE '%$searchq' OR itemname LIKE  '%$searchq'";
$result=mysql_query($order);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count>=1){
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $barcode=$row['barcode'];
                $itemname=$row['itemname'];
                $description=$row['description'];
                $amount=$row['amount'];
                $stocks=$row['stocks'];
                $location=$row['location'];
        }
            $output="<div>'.$barcode.' '.$itemname.' '.$description.' '.$amount.' '.$stocks.' '.$location.' </div>"; 
            }
            else
            {
            $output='no results';
            }
     }  
?>

<?php print("$output"); ?>
```